# Rowspan + colspan for whole row

Tags: html, html-table

Trying to get one cell inside a table, that will span to two rows and two columns.

Achieved this:

```html
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td style="min-width: 100px">R1C1</td>
        <td style="min-width: 100px">R2C2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='2' rowspan="3">R2C1, R3C1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">R4C1</td>
        <td rowspan="2">R4C2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JSfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/UmLqw/36/

Is there a way to get rid of those two cells to the right of R2?

**UPD2**

Ok, seems it's bit more complicated.

http://www.volleymsk.ru/ap/addons?section=Promotion

This is what i'm doing.

Comment: They shouldn't even be in the HTML. And if you have a single cell in each of the three rows it's occupying, don't use `rowspan`, just make it bigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you submit the code to an HTML5 validator like http://validator.w3.org/nu/, it will tell you (in a somewhat technical way) that the markup violates the HTML table model. You cannot define a row that has no cells starting on it. Instead of making one row two rows, you can set the height of a row as desired.

It is unclear what you actually want, but on the basis of your second jsfiddle, it seems that you actually need a single table instead of two tables:

```html
<table border cellspacing=0>
  <tr><td>R1C1 <td>R2C2 <td>R1C1 <td>R2C2
  <tr><td rowspan=2 colspan=2>R2C1, R3C1 <td colspan=2>R2C1
  <tr>                                   <td colspan=2>R3C1
  <tr><td>R4C1 <td>R4C2 <td>R4C1 <td>R4C2
</table>
```

Comment: Well, actually, you're right. But problem is, that table is filled with content from more, than 20 SQL queries. And first 10 quieres provide data for LEFT table and second 10 quieres - for RIGHT. I'll  think, how i can change output anyway. Thanks.

Comment: @AlexeyDerevyanko, that would be different question and should be posted separately. But it sounds like you should simply defer the writing of the data until you have got it all. That is, you should store the results in variables of your program and start generating the `table` element only after getting all the results.

Answer (score 1):

You have in `3rd` and `4th` row 3 table cells, in the others just two. In this case there is no reason using `rowspan` in the second row, when you have there also `colspan` over all cells.

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td style="min-width: 100px">R1C1</td>
        <td style="min-width: 100px">R2C2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='2'>R2C1, R3C1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">R4C1</td>
        <td rowspan="2">R4C2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UmLqw/38/

Comment: That won't work. Your span is just for ONE row, and i need for TWO.

Comment: I doesn´t make a sense to have rowspan > 1 and colspan through all column. It make from these rows only one. What you want to achieve? Can you send me a link to image how your table should looks like?

Answer (score 0):

you are not actually trying to get two rows, you just want to make one row bigger. the idea of row span is for it to be spanned among certain columns and not all.

you can achieve what you want through simple styling:

```
<table border="1">
        <tr>
        <td style="min-width: 100px">R1C1</td>
        <td style="min-width: 100px">R2C2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height:30px">
        <td colspan='2'>R2C1,R3C1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">R4C1</td>
        <td rowspan="2">R4C2</td>
    </tr>
        </table>
```

EDIT: use a column to count rows so you can use rowspan:

```
<table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
        <td style="min-width: 100px">R1C1</td>
        <td style="min-width: 100px">R2C2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr >
        <td >2</td>
        <td colspan='2'rowspan='2' >R2C1,R3C1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td >R4C1</td>
        <td >R4C2</td>
    </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: Well, actual table is a bit bigger than in my sample. There's not only 2 rows, but 5 rows and 3 rows, so i thought it'll be easier to stick with rowspan, than calculate rowheight in each case.

Comment: I'll use this answer for now. Thanks.

Comment: This means that you make wild guess on the height needed, instead of letting browsers apply normal table layout algorithms. Setting the height in pixels would even make the code font size dependent. If some height should match the height of a row in another table, you should use JavaScript to find that height and assign the same height.

Comment: actually yes, i was referring to this code as how it is possible to achieve that. it is always better to use a more dynamic way to set widths and heights. probably in % using js

Comment: That's exactly i was trying to avoid. That's why i answered "FOR NOW". Seems, i have to recode array for output, as you proposed. But that'll take more time and i need to provide my users with result right now. So for short-term i'll go with HEIGHT and i've added "recode output array" in long-term todo.